# Good exercises on groups, fields, rings etc

Tags: group-theory

I want to help out a friend with an upcoming test on structures such as groups, fields,  etc. Does anyone know good question of the form: is V,* a group? or what type of structure is V,*,# ((unital) ring, integral domain, field, etc)? Are V and Y homomorp? etc. Keep in mind that it is for a high school student. Thanks

Comment: You can look at the following books: (1). Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote. (first few problems in the first section of groups and rings.) (2). Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian. (3). A first course in Abstract Algebra by J.B. Fraleigh. Though these are more advance books than the level you mentioned, but these books also contains a good number of examples and exercises for the beginners.

Comment: for a little bit difficult problem you can go and have a look in the book Topics in Algebra by I.N Herstein

Answer (score 2):

***Groups:*** (1). Determine which of the following sets are group under addition:

(a) the set of all rationals (including $0$) in lowest term whose denominators are odd.

(b) the set of all rationals (including $0$) in lowest term whose denominators are even.

(c) the set of rationals whose absolute value $< 1.$

(d) the set of rationals whose absolute value $\geq 1$ together with $0.$

(2). Let $G:= \{a + b\sqrt 2 \mid a, b \in \mathbb Q \}.$

(a) Show that $G$ is a group under addition.

(b) Show that non-zero elements of $G$ forms a group under multiplication.

(3). Let $G:= \{z \in \mathbb C \mid z^n = 1$ for some $n \in \mathbb N \}$ (this one is little harder than the above two).

(a) Show that $G$ forms a group with respect to multiplication.

(b) Show that $G$ does not form a group with respect to addition.

Comment: 3b is false, actually. n may be 0 so G contains all complex numbers

Comment: 1a  no, b yes, c no, d no

Answer (score 1):

As a very easy warm up, how about asking questions about the basic number systems?

Does $\mathbb{Z}$ form a group with respect to addition? (Yes.) Does $\mathbb{Z}$ form a group with respect to multiplication? (No.) Does $\mathbb{Q}$ form a group with respect to addition? (Yes.) Trick question: does $\mathbb{Q}$ form a group with respect to multiplication? (No, $0$ has no inverse.) Does $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$ form a group with respect to multiplication? (Yes.) Does it form a group with respect to addition? (No, addition does not restrict to a total function on this domain.)

Comment: thanks. do you mean Q\{0} is not a group in respect to addition? or do you mean Q is not a group in respect to addition? Because the latter is, right?

Comment: The first one, of course. $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$ is not a group with respect to addition because $-1,1 \in \mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$ but $(-1)+1 \notin \mathbb{Q}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Ok, and also because it has no neutral element. thanks